# Login into Facebook using REMOTE_ADDR curl php

Tags: php, curl

Hello I want to login into Facebook using REMOTE IP. To ignore IP change Block. Well Everything is working. I have only IP Changing problem. when IP change Facebook Send Checkpoint And after allow IP still not working. SO please give me any solution how do this.

```
$ipku = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ip = array("REMOTE_ADDR: $ipku", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: $ipku");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://mbasic.facebook.com/login.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'charset_test=€,´,€,´,水,Д,Є&email='.urlencode($em).'&pass='.urlencode($pa).'&login=Login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$ip);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Opera/9.80 (Series 60; Opera Mini/6.5.27309/34.1445; U; en) Presto/2.8.119 Version/11.10');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,
"https://mbasic.facebook.com");
 $data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot spoof the IP Address of a Request.

The IP does not come from the HTTP header.

The IP is in the TCP/IP communications header between Browser and Server.  The HTTP is encapsulated in the TCP/IP.